# I have a problem when sending a direct message in the Python instagrapi package

Tags: python, instagram, instagrapi

```
from instagrapi import Client

cl = Client()
cl.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)    
    
pk_send = cl.media_pk_from_url("https://www.instagram.com/p/C2t3L9qoSAT/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link&igsh=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==")
post_send = cl.media_id(pk_send)

user_id = cl.user_id_from_username('alirezaevilx')

cl.direct_media_share(post_send, [user_id])
```

**after running it I get this error:**

```
Status 201: JSONDecodeError in public_request (url=https://www.instagram.com/alirezaevilx/?__a=1&__d=dis) >>> 
Status 201: JSONDecodeError in public_request (url=https://www.instagram.com/alirezaevilx/?__a=1&__d=dis) >>> 
Status 201: JSONDecodeError in public_request (url=https://www.instagram.com/alirezaevilx/?__a=1&__d=dis) >>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\IGbot\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    cl.direct_media_share(post_send, [user_id])
  File "C:\Python\IGbot\venv\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\mixins\direct.py", line 884, in direct_media_share
    return extract_direct_message(result["payload"])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\IGbot\venv\Lib\site-packages\instagrapi\extractors.py", line 335, in extract_direct_message
    data['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data['timestamp'] // 1_000_000)
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'
```

> **instagrapi version : 2.0.3**
>
> **pillow version : 10.2.0**

**The direct message is sent, but this error is displayed in the output and the program is completely stopped**

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I too have the same error but it happens just because of the import itself.

Comment: @BruceWayne I had to solve this problem with try and exception so that the program does not stop